# Отрицание фразы в python regex

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Хочу показать на примере, что мне нужно отловить (вон то, что между тегами):

```
[spoiler]a1 &-+[@ ]_ ':;!*[/spoiler]
```

Значения между границами могут быть абсолютно разные.
И по идее, как я видел в интернетах, должно быть что-то типа

```
re.findall(r'\[spoiler\]((?!\[/spoiler\])*)\[/spoiler\]', text)
```

Но это не работает. Что-то здесь не так. Видимо, всё не так...

Comment: Нет, всё проще, `re.findall(r'\[spoiler](.*?)\[/spoiler]', text, re.S)`

Comment: Да вы бог что ли... Всё работает

Answer (score -1):

`re.findall(r'\[spoiler](.*?)\[/spoiler]', text, re.S)`

Спасибо за решение юзеру [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182013/wiktor-stribiżew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182013/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)